# How to be on the same page in antd react js table after going on another component

Tags: reactjs, antd

For ex i am on page 2 of the table , i want to be on the same page after coming from another component.

Tried local storage ,but not go as expected

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

Using the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks: You can use the `useState` hook to store the data in the component's state, and then use the `useEffect` hook to retrieve the data from the cache and update the state when the component is mounted or updated.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const cachedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    if (cachedData) {
      setData(cachedData);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);

  // Render component Here
}
```